# Rails 2.3: Immediately redirect before after_filter executes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is in Rails 2.3.10 and Ruby 1.8.

I've got some code that looks roughly like this:

```
class RedirectingController
  after_filter :do_something_long, :only => [:show]
  def show
    redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
  end

  def do_something_long
    sleep 60
    logger.debug("Something long has completed")
  end
end
```

Now my problem is that even though I see in the logs that the redirect has been executed, it waits until sleep 60 is complete before the redirect actually happens.  Is there a way I can  have the redirect sent to the browser and then run do_something_long.  As a side note I am trying to avoid using something like delayed_job or resque.

Answer (score 0):

Something like delayed_job or resque is designed to initiate and complete long running background tasks instead of making the user wait for it to complete (and freezing up the ui). How long is the task going to take? If it completes in miliseconds then most people probably won't even notice, but if it takes longer than you should dig into delayed_job. Do you have a compelling reason or hangup as to why you can't?

Comment: I'll give some background: the action that's being hit is going be hit by a very large volume of users.  All the action is doing is redirecting (think bit.ly for a rough analogy) but there's some computation that needs to happen that I don't want to add to the time that it takes to redirect which will only take 0.5s at most.

Comment: Ok. Is there a compelling reason why you can use delayed job? It seems like a fairly good use case for this. They hit the action, you fire off to delayed job, and they are on their way lightning fast.

Comment: If I have to use delayed_job I will, but it seems like that would be a lot of overhead compared to just flushing the output, redirecting the browser, and then doing the calculation.  I also have concerns that the volume of database writes delayed_job would create in the database could impact the rest of the site.

Comment: Presumably you will have to do the calculation either way (same number of db writes) so delayed job vs delaying the user will impact the site the same. If you mean you are concerned that delayed_job writes (like the queing mechanism) will add a lot of database writes this shouldn't be an issue unless your site is huge. Even then you can probably optimize your db if you need to insert at 1000+ inserts a second.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
def do_something_long
  Thread.new do
    sleep 60
    logger.debug("Something long has completed")
  end
end
```

See [How to run a very small amount of code asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736051/how-to-run-a-very-small-amount-of-code-asynchronously)

Comment: I tried doing a thread.new block to do the computation but I'm getting a nil object exception whereas in single threaded mode it works without issue.  Are there known issues with using threads within a controller action?